# Nested JSONObject

Tags: java, json, nested

I am having several problems with JSONObjects and JSONArray.
I would like to parse this json file:

```
[{
  "SourceFile": "AndresIniesta.flv",
  "ExifTool": {
    "ExifToolVersion": 8.22
  },
  "System": {
    "FileName": "AndresIniesta.flv",
    (...)
  },
  "File": {
    "FileType": "FLV",
    "MIMEType": "video/x-flv"
  },
  "Flash": {
    "Duration": "04:09",
    "Starttime": 0,
    "Totalduration": 249.36,
    "ImageWidth": 320,
    (...)
  },
  "Composite": {
    "ImageSize": "320x240"
  }
}]
```

But not all of them, just the field Flash.
The whole file is an JSONArray, but with just 1 element. I got the Flash filled with this piece of code:

> JsonMappingException, IOException {
>
> > String a = new String();
> >     InputStream is =
> >     this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
> >         "a.json");
> >     String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString(is);
> >     JSONArray json = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonTxt);
> >     JSONObject flash = json.getJSONObject(0);
> >
> > System.out.print("flash -> " + flash.getString("Flash"));

But I don't know hoy to access to each one of Flash fild, lis Duration, Starttime... etc.

When I try it like this:

> String canseekontime =
>   flash.getString("Canseekontime");
>     int starttime =
>   flash.getInt("Starttime");
>   Double duration = flash.getDouble("Duration");

I get this error:
`net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["Duration"]` not found.

Any help??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean

```
JSONObject flash = json.getJSONObject(0); 
JSONObject Flash = flash.getJSONObject("Flash"); 
int starttime = Flash.getInt("Starttime");
```